# JasperReports - Missing value from bean

Tags: java, jasper-reports, javabeans

I'm creating a report on *Jaspersoft Studio*, on preview everything is fine.

There is only 3 fields on my report: nome, medida e bairro.

Inside my application, it's giving the error when i try to generate the report

My source codes:

**Class RelatorioUtils**

```
public static void executarRelatorio(String caminhoRelatorio, Map<String, Object> parametros, String nomeRelatorio, JRBeanCollectionDataSource fonteDados) throws IOException {
    FacesContext context = FacesContext.getCurrentInstance();
    HttpServletResponse response = (HttpServletResponse) context.getExternalContext().getResponse();

    //pegar caminho do relatorio jasper
    InputStream reportStream = context.getExternalContext().getResourceAsStream(caminhoRelatorio);
    response.setContentType("application/pdf");

    try {
        ServletOutputStream servletOutput = null;
        try {
            servletOutput = response.getOutputStream();
        } catch (IOException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }

        if (parametros == null) {
            parametros = new HashMap<String, Object>();
        }

        JasperRunManager.runReportToPdfStream(reportStream, servletOutput, parametros, fonteDados);

        try {
            servletOutput.flush();
            servletOutput.close();
        } catch (IOException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
    } catch (JRException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    } finally {
        context.getResponseComplete();
    }
}
```

**My Managed Bean**

```
public void emitir() {
    relatorios = dao.listarTodos();
    JRBeanCollectionDataSource fonteDados = new JRBeanCollectionDataSource(relatorios); // aqui está vindo completo meu JRbeanCollection está trazendo todos os dados que preciso
    FacesContext context = FacesContext.getCurrentInstance();
    ServletContext servletContext = (ServletContext) context.getExternalContext().getContext();


    try {
        RelatorioUtil.executarRelatorio("/relatorios/RelatorioMedidaCautelar.jasper", null, "Relatorio", fonteDados);
    } catch (IOException ex) {
        Logger.getLogger(MBRelatorio.class.getName()).log(Level.SEVERE, null, ex);
    }

}
```

**My bean**

```
enpublic class MedidaRelatorio {

private String nome;
private String bairro;
private String medida;

public MedidaRelatorio() {
}

public MedidaRelatorio(String nome, String bairro, String medida) {
    this.nome = nome;
    this.bairro = bairro;
    this.medida = medida;
}

public String getNome() {
    return nome;
}

public void setNome(String nome) {
    this.nome = nome;
}

public String getBairro() {
    return bairro;
}

public void setBairro(String bairro) {
    this.bairro = bairro;
}

public String getMedida() {
    return medida;
}

public void setMedida(String medida) {
    this.medida = medida;
}
```

}

And the error:

> net.sf.jasperreports.engine.JRException: Error retrieving field value from bean : at net.sf.jasperreports.engine.data.JRAbstractBeanDataSource.getBeanProperty(JRAbstractBeanDataSource.java:123) at net.sf.jasperreports.engine.data.JRAbstractBeanDataSource.getFieldValue(JRAbstractBeanDataSource.java:96) at net.sf.jasperreports.engine.data.JRBeanCollectionDataSource.getFieldValue(JRBeanCollectionDataSource.java:109) at net.sf.jasperreports.engine.fill.JRFillDataset.setOldValues(JRFillDataset.java:1358) at net.sf.jasperreports.engine.fill.JRFillDataset.next(JRFillDataset.java:1259) at net.sf.jasperreports.engine.fill.JRFillDataset.next(JRFillDataset.java:1235) at net.sf.jasperreports.engine.fill.JRBaseFiller.next(JRBaseFiller.java:1614) at net.sf.jasperreports.engine.fill.JRVerticalFiller.fillReport(JRVerticalFiller.java:150) at net.sf.jasperreports.engine.fill.JRBaseFiller.fill(JRBaseFiller.java:963) at net.sf.jasperreports.engine.fill.JRBaseFiller.fill(JRBaseFiller.java:892) at net.sf.jasperreports.engine.fill.JRFiller.fill(JRFiller.java:114) at net.sf.jasperreports.engine.JasperFillManager.fill(JasperFillManager.java:668) at net.sf.jasperreports.engine.JasperFillManager.fill(JasperFillManager.java:649) at net.sf.jasperreports.engine.JasperRunManager.runToPdfStream(JasperRunManager.java:437) at net.sf.jasperreports.engine.JasperRunManager.runReportToPdfStream(JasperRunManager.java:858) at br.com.agilles.medidas.utils.RelatorioUtil.executarRelatorio(RelatorioUtil.java:57) at br.com.agilles.medidas.beans.MBRelatorio.emitir(MBRelatorio.java:58) Caused by: java.lang.NoSuchMethodException: Unknown property '' on class 'class br.com.agilles.medidas.models.Relatorio' at org.apache.commons.beanutils.PropertyUtilsBean.getSimpleProperty(PropertyUtilsBean.java:1277) at org.apache.commons.beanutils.PropertyUtilsBean.getNestedProperty(PropertyUtilsBean.java:808) at org.apache.commons.beanutils.PropertyUtilsBean.getProperty(PropertyUtilsBean.java:884) at org.apache.commons.beanutils.PropertyUtils.getProperty(PropertyUtils.java:464) at net.sf.jasperreports.engine.data.JRAbstractBeanDataSource.getBeanProperty(JRAbstractBeanDataSource.java:111) ... 57 more

Can anyone help me?

Comment: You are using the missing field ***emitir***

Comment: 1) dao.listarTodos() needs to return class MedidaRelatorio and  not Relatorio.2) check that you don't have a field declaration in the jrxml with empty name (check the .jrxml file with notepad)

Comment: that's it Petter, there is a field description in my jrxml source code that was empty, just filled that field and works :D